# wp_send_json* functions do a weird float values conversion

Tags: ajax, wordpress

I have a method that does simple math and returns a float value. I use this value as an argument for `wp_send_json()` function. Values are converted in a way that I don't understand.

```php
$x = $calculator->getValue(); // Returns 3.02
$y = 3.02;

gettype($x); // Returns double
gettype($y); // Returns bouble

wp_send_json_success(%x); // prints {"success":false,"data":3.0199999999999996}
wp_send_json_success($y); // prints {"success":false,"data":3.02}
```

I don't' understand it at all. Both `$x` and `$y` values are exactly the same in terms of values and types. So why the outputs produced by `wp_send_json_success` are different?

---

Update:

Now I'm even more confused

```php
$x === $y; // returns false
$x == $y; // returns false too!
```

How is it possible? When I do `var_dump` I can see that the values are the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It has nothing to do with `wp_send_json()`. In my code the `3.02` value returned by the `$calculator->getValue()` method is a result of a `10 - 6.98` equation. It returns `3.0199999999999996` but when I `var_dump` it then the result on the screen is rounded to `3.02`. That's why `$x == $y` returns false.